# Check whether it is the same file even after moving, renaming etc

Tags: file

This problem might be a common one, but since I don't know the terms associated with it, I couldn't search for it (unless Google accepted entire paragraphs as search queries).

I have a file - Can be a text file, or an MP3 file or a video clip or even a HUGE mkv file.

I have access to this file and now I have to process it in some way so that I get some kind of a value or unique identifier.. a hash, or something. I store it somewhere. This "hash" has to be small - several byte. It shouldnt be half the file size!

Later on, when I am presented with a file again, I have to verify whether it was the same original file using that value I got in step 1. I will NOT have access to the original file this time. All I have will be that value from step 1.

This algorithm should return true if the second file contains the exact same data - every single bit - as the first file (basically the same file) even if the file name, attributes, location etc have all changed.

Basically I need to know whether I am dealing with the same file, even if it moved, renamed and has all its attributes changed - but when NOT having access to both the files at the same time.

This has to be OS or FileSystem independent.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are [cryptographic hash algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). Read about them:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

All robust languages and libraries offer support for calculating hashes.

Comment: What are the odds that two SHA-1 or two MD5 hashes will collide for two different files?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, zero. edit: i misunderstood your question. Slightly less than zero, but still very, very low. If that's a concern, you can store SHA1 *and* MD5 for each file, and the odds of *those* colliding are practically zero.

Comment: You mean, I calculate both SHA-1 and MD5 for each file. Compare both of the RESPECTIVE hashes. Both of them colliding respectively is impossible. Right? I guess it is overkill though.

Comment: Yeah, and that would be overkill. You can search Google for articles, papers and blog posts on hash collisions. Check http://www.backupcentral.com/mr-backup-blog-mainmenu-47/13-mr-backup-blog/145-de-dupe-hash-collisions.html

Answer (score 1):

Your dilemma is simple. Get an MD5 (or whatever algorithm can produce 1 way hash) hash every time you process the file.

```
Here it is in simple steps:
Step 1: Load file stream into a byte array
Step 2: Obtain MD5 hash from byte array
Step 3: Check your db if it already contains hash.
Step 4:    return false if not exist
Step 5:    return true if found
Step 6: If not exist process file
Step 7: Save hash
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare two files by a key `( file-1(1,20,a), file-2(2,20,a))` Using sort card , matched records should be moved to **file-3 (a new file) from file file-2** ?